# Do you ever get to fly anything else (other than drones) in X-Rebirth?

Tags: x-rebirth

I loved flying all the different ship types in X3 (and its various flavors).  I especially liked flying the more ponderous (and more deadly) ships.

As near as I can tell, in X-Rebirth, you never get to fly anything other than the Albion Skunk and occasional drones.  I know that you can pick up other ships for your fleet but do you ever get to drive the other ships from the cockpit?

Answer (score 5):

**No.** As you mentioned in your question you are **limited to** your one and only ship - the **albion skunk** - and **drones**. You can get other ships for your fleet but you won't be able to fly them by yourself. But you should be able to land on a capital ship of your fleet, walk to the bridge and give orders to the captain. So it's more like a passiv-mode, then actually flying those ships.

In addition I would like to point out, that the X series is very well known for their modding community. So it may be possible to fly other ships with some mods later on :)